# Pasar parámetros de Javascritp a php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

tengo un archivo que recibe Geolocalizacion.php donde tiene el cuerpo de la página y tengo la variable

```
$lat = isset($_POST['tuVariable']) ? $_POST['tuVariable'] : '';
```

cuando le doy clic a un boton le paso estos datos desde el js:

```
      var txtX3 = document.getElementById("txtX3").value;
      var x =  txtX3.substring(0,3);
      var url = "Geolocalizacion.php";                 
              
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {tuVariable:x},
      }).done(function(data){

        console.log(data);// return data php
        header('Location: Geolocalizacion.php');
      });
```

pero no lo hace que se debe ya puse también el código script para que ejecute el ajax

Comment: `header` **redirige** tu navegación al php pero no le está enviando nada. Lo que no sabemos es qué pasa con el `$.ajax` y qué sale en el `console.log` o por qué dices que no lo hace (no es evidente). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario  y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No tienes que poner esto para pasar los datos vía Ajax: `header('Location: Geolocalizacion.php');`, porque esta herramienta usa el parámetro `url` para eso. Como bien dice @Alfabravo, lo que hará `header` ahí será redirigir. Por otra parte, ¿ese es todo el código en `Geolocalizacion.php`? Si no imprimes nada desde tu PHP no verás respuesta ninguna en la consola.

Comment: como indica @Alfabravo el header no te va a permitir ver la respuesta del servidor ya que done es un evento que ocurre cuando se ha ejecutado correctamente todo y el header te va a redirigir al php ... si quieres ver una respuesta del servidor para pruebas quita el header ...